# How to move Windows 7 boot/Bitlocker partition to the end of a drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, bitlocker

I upgraded from a 250 GB hard drive to a 1.5 TB hard drive.  I cloned the data from the old drive onto the new drive.  Now I want to expand my main partition (C:) to take up the additional space.  Unfortunately, there is a 300 MB partition directly after the C: partition, which I believe is the Bit Locker boot drive.

Is there a way to move the 300 MB partition to the end of the available space so that I can expand the C: partition?  Or is there some other way to get the C: drive to take advantage of the additional space without formatting and reinstalling?

Answer (score 3):

You can boot a [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) boot CD which will let you move the 300 MB partition to the end and expand C.

Comment: you need to boot off the CD because you can't modify any partitions that you've currently mounted. (Just a bit of extra info)